# Write to file at particular index

Tags: java, file, writer

I need to write to a file at a particular index position. `BufferedWriter` and `PrintWriter` does not allow writing to an index. How do I go about achieving this?

Basically what i want to do is if a file contains an empty line at the EOF then i need to write at that position, else insert a new line and write. Copying the contents of the file to a temporary file and then deleting the original file and then again renaming the temporary file to the original file's name isn't an option.

Thanks

Comment: If you write at a random location in a text file its likely to be in the middle of a line, and possibly in the middle of a multi-byte character. How do you know it will be at the start of a line? BTW: You cannot insert into a file only re-write everything from the point you are up to.

Comment: @Peter: We're talking EOF here, not random position. If you are going to the EOF, you won't be in a middle of a multi-bytes char. And you can check if the previous byte is a CR or LF character to know if you are at the beginning of a new line or not.

Comment: @Vivien, That is not what I understand from "I need to write to a file at a particular index position. " If all the OP wants to do is append to the file, this can be done without an "insert"

Comment: @Peter: The second part of the question explains the problem with more details. From what I understand from the explanation, it is about appending to the file.

Comment: It would be useful of the OP could clarify what he/she is trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

Using this class, you can go to a specific location using the `seek(long)` method and write using the different `write` methods.

In the case of your particuliar problem, the best solution weems to be
to use a `RandomAccessFile` and navigate to the end of your file. Check if this is a new line, write, close.

Comment: Will i have `OutOfMemory` problems if the file contains very large amount of data?

Comment: No. A RandomAccessFile does NOT load the whole file in memory. All manipulations are done directly on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Given is the method to write content at particular position.

Lets say my file is **Test.txt** and content is as follow

```
Hello 
How are you
Today is Monday
```

now you want to write "*hi*" after hello. So the offset for "*hi*" will be "5".

Method is :

```
filename = "test.txt";
offset = 5;
byte[] content = ("\t hi").getBytes();

private void insert(String filename, long offset, byte[] content) throws IOException {

    RandomAccessFile r = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
    RandomAccessFile rtemp = new RandomAccessFile(filename+"Temp", "rw");
    long fileSize = r.length(); 
    FileChannel sourceChannel = r.getChannel();
    FileChannel targetChannel = rtemp.getChannel();
    sourceChannel.transferTo(offset, (fileSize - offset), targetChannel);
    sourceChannel.truncate(offset);
    r.seek(offset);
    r.write(content);
    long newOffset = r.getFilePointer();
    targetChannel.position(0L);
    sourceChannel.transferFrom(targetChannel, newOffset, (fileSize - offset));
    sourceChannel.close();
    targetChannel.close();
    rtemp.close();
    r.close();

}
```

The output will be:

```
Hello hi
How are you
Today is Monday
```